# Flask-admin - генерируемые поля

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Проблема с генерируемыми полями в flask-admin. Существует модель

```
class Article(db.Model, Base):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String())
    description = db.Column(db.Text())
    url = db.Column(db.String())

    created_on = db.Column(db.DateTime(), server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_on = db.Column(db.DateTime(), server_default=db.func.now(), onupdate=db.func.now())

    author = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    category = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('category.id'))

    def __init__(self, title="", description="", author="", category=""):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.category = category
        self.description = description

        self.url = slugify(title)
```

Формой передается 4 значения (title, description, author, category), 5 поле (url) должно сгенерироваться само (self.url = slugify(title)), но этого не происходит

Данная форма была сгенерированна flask-admin'ом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Создайте метод, типа save(), и уже в нём производите манипуляции:

```
@staticmethod
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.url:
        self.url = slugify(self.title)
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

P.S. Я не уверен, что метод, который я написал, будет работать так как нужно, но вообще сделать то что вы хотите можно именно подобным образом.